# Proper syntax for using a Jquery variable with return

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to alter a div's numeric content when a form is submitted and am using the following jQuery on :submit, but I'm unsure if I'm using the proper syntax for the variable in the second part, as it's not working.

```
// gets the contents of the selected option, and strips everything before the "$" and all non-numeric characters save the decimal
var changingprice = $('#mydiv .cartbutton form :selected')
.text()
.split('$')
.pop()
.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');

// jQuery to update the content of the #cart-price-counter div. 
$('#cart-price-counter')
.html(function(i, val) {
 return (val*1+changingprice).toFixed(2);
 });
```

Comment: Try to check if your first selector is correct. Print or alert "$('#mydiv .cartbutton form :selected').length" and if its 1 then your selector is working.

Comment: I've used alert to check it, and the var is indeed returning my desired value. Additionally, your method is returning a 1. It (the var) just does not appear to be working when included in the return. On a related note, replacing the var with a random number works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` for `changingprice` like,

```
$('#cart-price-counter')
   .html(function(i, val) {
        return (val*1+parseFloat(changingprice)).toFixed(2);
    });
```

Comment: Rohan, you're my hero. That did it. Marking yours as the answer as soon as SO lets me.